# How can increase default font size in Windows Server 2016 VM

Tags: windows, hyper-v, windows-server-2016

I have setup a Windows Server 2016 VM on my Windows 10 machine using Hyper V.
When i start and connect to the VM, I want to increase the default font size in the windows 2016 env. But when I go to setting, I got the error message saying that i can't adjust font size due to i am in a remote session.

Can you please tell me how can I fix the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There's a MS hotfix to allow per-user changing of the font-size settings in an rdp session, please try the following link to see if helps.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2726399